# How to push data from fetch() to array in Javascript using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch, javascript-objects

I'm trying to fetch data from several urls stored in an array. Each url contains data in json format. I'm using a for loop to iterate over the urls stored in the url array. Each json file contains the `travelTimeInSeconds` value I'm interested in. When running the following code, the two values stored in the `timeT` variable are logged in the console. However, the `ttTimes` array remains empty. How do get the values to be stored in the `ttTimes` array?

```
urls = ['www.a.com/dataa.json','www.b.com/datab.json']
ttTimes = []

function getData(url) {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response=>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data =>{
        let timeT = Math.round(data['routes'][0]['summary']['travelTimeInSeconds']/60); 
        console.log(timeT)
        ttTimes.push(timeT)
    })

}

for (url in urls){
    time = getData(urls[url])
    console.log(time)
    ttTimes.push(time)
};
```

Comment: 1. `getData` doesn't return anything 2. `fetch` is async, so even if you fix (1), `time` will contain a Promise, not `timeT` (which also isn't returned inside the callback) 3. to run multiple async functions, use `Promise.all` (this will return an array containing the results, exactly what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/41axsLw6/

Comment: Note that: yes, you're not returning anything but instead pushing to `ttTimes`; *but*: while this works in theory, the requests runs at the same time and will finish a) in an unspecified order b) at some point in the future, long after the `console.log(ttTimes)` you probably have in your code somewhere

Comment: Thanks! Your solution also works. Is there a way to return `ttTimes` to be used in another function instead of just logging it to the console?

Comment: You can make the variable global again, but keep in mind that any function that uses it must be called *after* `ttTimes` has been set. Once you enter `async`, you cannot leave again. The idea is to put everything inside `main`, in order, and use `await` for async stuff. That way you can write "synchronous" code. I changed the above fiddle to show what I mean.

Comment: okay. Thanks. Is there a different way to get the data from the urls stored in the `urls` array that allows `ttTimes` to be returned and used in a new function?

Comment: As soon as you use fetch, you're dealing with async code. You can use `.then()` and callbacks, or async/await. But no matter what you do, you *need to make sure* the rest of your code runs *after* the fetch requests have finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ttTimes` array remains empty because you never wait for the promises to resolve before checking it. You could use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them before checking on the results array.

```js
urls = ['www.a.com/dataa.json','www.b.com/datab.json']

// This function just returns a promise
function getData(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response=>{
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(data =>{
      const timeT = Math.round(data['routes'][0]['summary']['travelTimeInSeconds']/60); 
      return Promise.resolve(timeT);
    })
}


Promise.all(
  // use the urls to create an array of promises
  urls.map(getData)
).then((ttTimes) => {
  // When all the promises have been resolved, then this will be executed
  //Here all the promises have been resolved, so you would have an array with the ttTimes
  console.log(ttTimes);
})
```